# Login with username or email Laravel fortify fails validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm new to laravel, I'm creating a login system where a user can login with username or email. When I submit the form, it returns with an error `The username field is required.`

LoginRequest.php

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            Fortify::username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
```

FortifyServiceprovider.php

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (LoginRequest $request) {
            $user = User::where('email', $request->username)
                ->orWhere('username', $request->username)->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
      return $user;
    });
```

Fortify.php

```
'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],
```

login.blade.php

```
<form class="mt-4" action="login" method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" value="{{ old('username') }}" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
   @error('username')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
   @enderror
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label" for="userpassword">Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="userpassword"
      placeholder="Enter password">
   @error('password')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
   @enderror
</div>
</form>
```

Please any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are you sending `username` ? Share your HTML/Blade form please

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes I am

Comment: I realized that I didn't add ```name``` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add name attribute to both input fields username and password

login.blade.php

```
    <form class="mt-4" action="login" method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
   @error('username')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
   @enderror
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
   <label class="form-label" for="userpassword">Password</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" id="userpassword"
      placeholder="Enter password">
   @error('password')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
   @enderror
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your code, what it does and how does it answers the question.

Comment: I did, Thank you